# Global [multiple sessions] directory stack

Tags: shell, zsh

For the current zsh session I use `dirs -v` command to print the directory stack.

I'd like to have an analogous tool that shows me the directory stack of all sessions, also the closed ones. Or if not a stack, then a history of directories I have been in.

I have some ideas how to do it, but maybe there exists a nice clean solution which does exactly this.